# Create GLKView in two class in OpenGLES?

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es

currently i am working in game application, Already i have one viewcontroller (and make GLKView), now another one viewcontroller then how to customize a GLKView, please help me

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it's possible to create two GLKView, just like it's possible to create any two views.

```
GLKView *view1 = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
GLKView *view2 = [[GLKView alloc] initWithFrame:...];
```

I suspect you are also asking about whether the `GLKViewController` can have two `GLKViews` to control. I'm pretty sure you can only have one `GLKView` per `GLKViewController` if you want to use the `GLKViewController`'s frame management features. But you can easily replicate it by hand using the `CADisplayLink`.

Take a look at this tutorial, it's really helpful:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5223/beginning-opengl-es-2-0-with-glkit-part-1